# Automating restore from Blob storage with Powershell, but error Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I've put together the below script to automate a restore from Blob Storage to an on-premises SQL Server.

It fails however if a connection is left open with the following error:
"Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use"

I thought the following clause would solve the problem, but it doesn't.

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "ALTER DATABASE [Warehouse] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE" -ServerInstance "SQL1" -Database "Master"
```

Does anyone know what I can add/change within the script below to stop this problem from occurring in the future?

```
Import-Module SqlServer
$smo = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server $env:SQL1
$RelocateData = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile("Warehouse", "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Warehouse.mdf")
$RelocateLog = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile("Warehouse_Log", "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Warehouse.ldf")

#Restore database directly from Auzre
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "ALTER DATABASE [Warehouse] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE" -ServerInstance "SQL1" -Database "Master"
Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance "SQL1" -Database "Warehouse" -BackupFile "https://xxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/backup/Warehouse.bak" -RelocateFile @($RelocateData,$RelocateLog) -ReplaceDatabase

#Email any errors
if($Error) {Send-MailMessage -To "xxxx@xxx" -From "xxx@xx" -Subject "Warehouse restore job has errors" -Body [String]$Error -SmtpServer "xxxxxxxxxxxx" -Port "25"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some testing and yeah, it seems that the session doing `ALTER DATABASE [Warehouse] SET OFFLINE...` (or SINGLE_USER for that matter) can have locks against the database which would prevent it from dropping out.

You can probably invoke the following command after that call:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
select @sql = string_agg(concat('kill ',request_session_id), ';')
from sys.dm_tran_locks
where resource_database_id = DB_id('Warehouse')
group by request_session_id;
EXEC(@sql)
" -ServerInstance "SQL1" -Database "Master"
```

`

Comment: Thanks so much siggemannen, will give it a test and let you know :)